# Associative array in Delphi , array with string key is possible?

Tags: arrays, delphi, key, associative, delphi-xe3

If you work with php you can see the php have associative array (or array width string key) in programing lang.
For example:

```
$server['hostname']  =  'localhost';
$server['database']  =  'test';
$server['username']  =  'root';
$server['password']  =  'password' ;    

// 2d array
$all['myserver']['hostname'] = 'localhost' ;
```

But can't find any default way to use associative array in delphi.

First I want find default way with out any output component or class .
Second if really I cant find with internal way I force choose output classes only.

I use Delphi XE3 , many thanks for your help.

edit:
I found one class here : `http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26334` 
same as php , but any better way?

Comment: A very nice implementation of Associative Array in Delphi can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854846/1022219 . It is closest match to PHP's Assoc Array

Comment: @iPath: agree with thanks : )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use tStrings and tStringList for this purpose, but 2d arrays are out of the scope of these components.

Usage;

```
var
  names  : TStrings;
begin
  ...
  names := TStringList.Create;
  ...
  ...
  names.values['ABC'] := 'VALUE of ABC' ;
  ...
  ...
end ;
```

Comment: should be := (the assignment operator) not = which compares two values/ objects

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`TDictionary<string,string>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) from the `Generics.Collections` unit.

```
var
  Dict: TDictionary<string,string>;
  myValue: string;
....
Dict := TDictionary<string,string>.Create;
try
  Dict.Add('hostname', 'localhost');
  Dict.Add('database', 'test');
  //etc.
  myValue := Dict['hostname'];
finally
  Dict.Free;
end;
```

And so on and so on.

If you want a dictionary that contains a dictionary, you can do use `TDictionary<string, TDictionary<string,string>>`.

However, when you do that you'll need to take special care over the lifetime of the dictionary items that are contained in the outer dictionary. You can use `TObjectDictionary<K,V>` to help manage that for you. You'd create one of these objects like this:

```
TObjectDictionary<string, TDictionary<string,string>>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
```

This `TObjectDictionary<k,V>` operates the same was as a traditional `TObjectList` with `OwnsObjects` set to `True`.

Comment: here is not complete way i found better in here : http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26334 , but i want complete class , but Thank you David :)

Comment: I don't understand that comment. What you are looking for are the classes described in my answer.

Comment: tDictionary was introduced in newer Delphi versions. This solution is far better than the one that I gave with tStrings. Because the implementation of tDictionary is better than tStrings.

Comment: I envy those of you using Delphi 2009 onwards.... I am forced to used TStringList

Comment: @MaxCarroll Yes, that's not very much fun at all!

Comment: is there a way to get keys too ? for example `Dict.key[0]` ?!

Comment: @peiman the rtl dictionary has Keys and Values properties that expose the keys and values. But the rtl dictionary is not ordered, so acessing by integer index is not possible. For that you need the spring4d dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem that simple way (example):

```
uses StrUtils;

...

const const_TypesChar : array [0..4] of String =
    (
      'I',
      'F',
      'D',
      'S',
      'B'
    );
const const_TypesStr : array [0..4] of String =
    (
      'Integer',
      'Float',
      'Datetime',
      'String',
      'Boolean'
    );

...

Value := const_TypesStr[ AnsiIndexStr('S', const_TypesChar) ];

// As an example, after execution of this code Value variable will have 'String' value.

//
```

Then in program we are using two arrays **const_TypesChar** and **const_TypesStr** as one associative array with **AnsiIndexStr** function.

The plus is that it's simple and that we don't need to change code in different places in program every time when we add elements to our arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **ArrayS**. You can use associative arrays which stores predefined type of data (integer, string, boolean, float), or any of them. For example, below I define an associative array of floats:

```
uses ArrayS;

var floats : IFltArray;

floats := CreateArray;
floats['first'] := 0.1;
floats['second'] := 0.2;
writeln( floats['second'] );
```

And so on.

**Updated at 2020-03-15**

[Zipped source code](http://www.delphikingdom.com/zip/arrays.zip)

[Ussage example](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=868) in Russian

Comment: 404 unfortunately

Comment: [The zipped source code](http://www.delphikingdom.com/zip/arrays.zip) and [ussage example](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=868) in Russian.