# change the variable of which the name is given as input (Pascal)

Tags: delphi

I would like to know if there's a basic way to solve this issue. Also especially interested in specific solutions for Pascal.

Let say we have a form with 2 inputs: 'InputVARIABLE' and 'InputVALUE'.

In the InputVARIABLE area the user types the name of a variable he want to change. In the InputVALUE area the user types the value of this variable.

So for inputtexts 'color' and 'blue': how can I change the variable VAR_color without using IF statements like:

```
If InputVARIABLE.Text = 'color' Then VAR_color := InputVALUE.Text;
```

Is there for instance some function like:

```
ChangeVariable(InputVARIABLE.Text, InputValue.Text)
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: This could be done with extended `RTTI`. But I think that the extended `RTTI` syntax is not in freepascal (if that is your compiler) at the moment. In Delphi that is included since Delphi-2010.

Comment: I'm using Delphi! So can you give an example of how to solve such a problem?

Comment: Do a websearch for rtti

Comment: Anyway rtti is the answer to the question you asked but a dictionary may well be the solution to your real problem.

Comment: I agree with @David: most likely the best solution to your actual problem has nothing to do with 'changing the value of a variable known by its source-code name'. After all, this RTTI stuff is a rather new invention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't access symbols in Pascal using their name in a textual representation (string)

Object Pascal/Delphi have some extensions for this, but they are mainly meant for specific purposes (by e.g. allowing a framework to stream data without knowing it), and less for normal code.

So a change in plan is needed. Usually you look up the names in an array of variablenames (or tstringlist if Object Pascal), and if a valid match is found, then you use the index to set the result in an array.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to change actual variables predefined in delphi you can actually do something else.

All you really want is to save key - value pairs.

This in other languages is called an associative array / dictionary / key-value pairs

So you can say

```
Arr['color'] := 'red';
```

or say

```
Arr[edit1.Text] := edit2.Text;
```

then in reverse

```
Caption := Arr['color'];
```

would set the caption to 'red' or whatever is in edit2.text, you can add as many as you want to this.

If you have a older version of Delphi you could do the same with the Tlist class, just not nesting.

```
arr:= TStringList.Create;
arr.Add('color=red');
s := arr.Values['color'];
arr.free;
```

I needed nesting too so I made an associative array class using the dictionary in delphi XE3 that might help you more in the future too.

```
unit assoc;

interface

uses System.Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils;

type TAssoc = class
  private
    fVal: Variant;
    fStrict: Boolean;
    fDict: TDictionary<Variant,TAssoc>;
    function GetItem(Index: Variant): TAssoc;
    procedure SetVal(v: Variant);
    function GetVal:Variant;
  public
    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the TAssocnode by default allowing you to chain Nodes 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Index">
    ///   Search index, can be any primitive type.
    /// </param>
    property Items[Index: Variant]: TAssoc read GetItem; default;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Use this to read and write a node value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   can be almost everything Try not to use objects in here.
    /// </value>
    property Val:Variant read GetVal write SetVal;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gives you a direct link to the tdictionary object alowing you to
    ///   itterate
    /// </summary>
    property All:TDictionary<Variant,TAssoc> read fDict;
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Usefull for creating keys in strict mode
    ///   </para>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Array.add('key');<br />Array['key'].Val = 1;
    ///   </para>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Wich would throw an error in strict mode as 'key' is not defined
    ///     <br />In non strict mode it will just be created for you
    ///   </para>
    /// </summary>
    function Add(Index: Variant):TAssoc; overload;
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Usefull for creating keys in strict mode and setting its value at the same time
    ///   </para>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Array.add('key',1);<br />Array['key'].Val = 1;
    ///   </para>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Wich would throw an error in strict mode as 'key' is not defined
    ///     <br />In non strict mode it will just be created for you
    ///   </para>
    /// </summary>
    function Add(Index: Variant; Value: Variant):TAssoc; overload;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Strictmode will raise an exception when you try to:<br />- set a nod
    ///   that was already set instead of overwriting it.<br />- read a node
    ///   that was nto set
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strictRules">
    ///   Strictmode on of off
    /// </param>
    constructor Create(strictRules:Boolean);
    destructor Free;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Clears all underlying nodes
    /// </summary>
    procedure Clear;
end;

type TAssocEnum = TPair<Variant, TAssoc>;

implementation

{ TAssoc }

function TAssoc.Add(Index: Variant): TAssoc;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if(fDict<>nil) then begin // see if dict is or can be made
    if(fDict.ContainsKey(Index)) then begin // see if the key is in there
      if(fStrict = true) then begin // duplicate keys not strict
        raise Exception.Create('Dictionary is in strict mode, the key "'+Index+'" was already set.');
      end;
    end else begin // dict made, just not the key
      Result := TAssoc.Create(fStrict);
      fDict.Add(Index,Result);
    end;
  end else begin // dict not found
    begin // make dict and key
      fDict := TDictionary<Variant,TAssoc>.Create(1);
      Result := TAssoc.Create(fStrict);
      fDict.Add(Index,Result);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TAssoc.Add(Index, Value: Variant): TAssoc;
begin
  Result := Add(Index);
  Result.Val := Value;
end;

procedure TAssoc.Clear;
var
  Enum: TPair<Variant, TAssoc>;
begin
  if(fDict<>nil) then begin
    for Enum in fDict do begin
      Enum.Value.Free;
    end;
  end;
  fDict.Clear;
end;

constructor TAssoc.Create(strictRules:Boolean);
begin
  fStrict := strictRules;
  fDict := nil;
  TVarData(fVal).VType := varEmpty;
end;

destructor TAssoc.Free;
var
  Enum: TPair<Variant, TAssoc>;
begin
  if(fDict<>nil) then begin
    for Enum in fDict do begin
      Enum.Value.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TAssoc.GetItem(Index: Variant): TAssoc;
var
  v: Variant;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if(fdict<>nil) then begin // see if dict is or can be made
    if(fDict.ContainsKey(Index)) then begin // see if the key is in there
      Result := fDict.Items[Index];
    end else begin // dict made, just not the key
      if (fStrict) then begin
        raise Exception.Create('Dictionary is in strict mode, the key "'+Index+'" was not set.');
      end else begin // if not set, create the index and make it into a assocnode
        Result := TAssoc.Create(fStrict);
        fDict.Add(Index,Result);
      end;
    end;
  end else begin // if the key is not in there see if strict or not
    if(fStrict) then begin // if strict then error index not set
      raise Exception.Create('Dictionary is in strict mode, the key "'+Index+'" was not set.');
    end else begin // if not set, create the index and make it into a assocnode
      fDict := TDictionary<Variant,TAssoc>.Create(1);
      Result := TAssoc.Create(fStrict);
      fDict.Add(Index,Result);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TAssoc.GetVal: Variant;
begin Result := fVal; end;

procedure TAssoc.SetVal(v: Variant);
begin fVal := v; end;

// todo:
// make a kickass helper class
// output xml/json
// walk through tree
// parentnode property?
// make a delphi7 version using stringlist? (not worth it)
// have fun

end.
```

Simple Usage

```
Arr := TAssoc.Create(False);
Arr['color'].Val := 'red';
Arr[edit1.text].Val := edit2.text;
Arr.Free;
```

Advanced Usage

```
Arr := TAssoc.Create(False);
Arr['cuzz']['cdcollection'][1]['name'].Val := 'Mika Album'; // set cd
Arr['cuzz']['cdcollection'][2]['name'].Val := 1;            // set cd
Arr['cuzz']['cdcollection'][1]['name'].Val := 'Delphi 5';   // overwrite cd
Arr['cuzz']['cdcollection']['last']['name'].Val := 'Delphi xe3';   // overwrite cd
// list all cd's
for Enum in Arr['cuzz']['cdcollection'].All do begin
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Property "'+String(Enum.Key)+'" holds "'+String(Enum.Value['name'].Val));
end;
Arr.Free;
```

Delphi rocks!
Enjoy.